# What is the advantage of making the user use 'apt update' then 'apt upgrade'?

Tags: apt

To me it seems like needless hassel for the lay user but I assume there must be some advantage over just automatically updating the repository when the user wants to upgrade.

Comment: It saves resources.  If I update, install a program then perform upgrade - your method would cause the update to occur twice in that circumstance wasting cpu, energy & bandwidth. As a user you may not care thinking because it took you an extra second to type the `sudo apt update;` , but in an automated environment there is no second saved, and that process can occur multiple times.  This is only one advantage.

Comment: There's no advantage, that's just how package managers with remote repository support work: get list of items available in remote repo first, then upgrade what's possible.

Comment: There are package managers and wrappers for package managers (like Termux's pkg) that do updating automatically, hence when I'm asking.

Comment: "advantage" I suppose would be an opinion, it is just the way apt / apt-get have always worked. It gives Debian / Ubuntu character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` is separated by `upgrade`, because `upgrade` is not the only command you can run on an updated local package index.

- `apt upgrade`: upgrade all packages
- `apt list`: lists all packages with search name, supports glob
- `apt search`: searches packages with search name or description, supports regex
- `apt show`: shows information on a package
- `apt policy`: shows installation policy for a package

Combining these commands with `update` would be very inefficient. For todays desktop user with high-speed internet it seems to be obsolete. But for a sysadmin or some scripted solutions this is still relevant.

---

As a simple "workaround" you could add a function `aptup` to your `bashrc`:

```
echo 'aptup () { sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade; }' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

(Remove the `-y` if you want to be asked for confirmation before upgrading).

Then you can run `aptup` to `update` and `upgrade` the system.